# Background apps not working

Tags: applications, background-process

I use this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evozi.network) on SM-J7 with Android 8 to check my internet connectivity. I hardly *use* this app as I get to see what I require in the notification bar. But every day, I am forced to manually open it to make it work.

I also face the same issue with [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.noople.autotransfer.lite) but [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=you.in.spark.access.dots) one works fine, although both of them run in the background.

I have installed the same apps on another device (SM-M30 with Android 10) but there the apps start working on their own after the phone is switched on.

What is causing this? Any remedy?

Comment: Without knowing your device, have you checked the guide on [Don't kill my app!](https://dontkillmyapp.com/)?

Comment: @AndrewT. As per its suggestion, I disabled the app from the list of battery optimisation. Still, no result :(